# What does this error mean ? "Expected an indented block" Python

Tags: python

My code is the following:

```
    def value(one,two):
if one < two:
return two
else:
return one
```

Every time I try to run it, it gives the following error :

> IndentationError: expected an indented block

I tried rewriting the code, and still nothing happened.

Comment: It means you need to fix your indentation

Comment: what is an indentation?

Comment: the first (maybe second) thing you read in any tutorial.

Comment: Before you get jumped on and flagged here, remember that for Python, indentation is the fundamental, first lesson you need to know.

Comment: Also, regarding stack overflow etiquette, be sure to search for other answers that might help before posting your own. You'll probably see this question voted down by some folks, and perhaps be jumped on, because this is a frequently asked, and thoroughly answered question. I'm not attacking you for it, just introducing you to stack overflow as well as python. There are some users who may attack, but don't take it personally. Just a part of the wide world. (Most of us have asked something and been flagged as duplicates at one time or another.) Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Python uses (requires) indentation to identify blocks in your code. For example:

```
def value(one,two):
    if one < two: 
        return two
    else:
        return one
```

You have something along the lines of:

```
def value(one,two):
if one < two: 
return two
else:
return one
```

Which yields the error you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous guys said in their answers, you ***must*** indent every piece of code that it's inside another.

Why? You may ask.

Good question, glad you asked. See, Python doesn't have curly braces `{}`, therefore it ***has*** to know somehow where a block starts and ends; here comes the indentation. It may see trivial in other languages that do have curly braces, such as Java or C#, it is a must in Python.

For every code, if it's inside another (A function, a loop, an if statement, and so on) it has to be indented 4 spaces (Or a `tab` key), **no more, no less**.

Of course, if you have another code inside the already indented one, you just add another 4 spaces, and so on as long as you need to.

As for your code, it should be like this:

```
def value(one,two):
    if one < two: 
        return two
    else:
        return one
```

Always remember indentation, it is Python's essence!

Good luck :)