# Urllib get request with loop

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to learn coding by doing.Here is the script that I tried to write:

```
import urllib.request

template_name_list = ['Summercity_171128',
'171219_Quarter']

file_name_list = ['Summercity_171128',
'171219_Quarter']

for template_name, file_name in zip(template_name_list, file_name_list):


url = 'http://api.whatcounts.net/bin/api_web?r=relayrides&p=******&c=gettemplatebyname&template_name='+str(template_name)+'&output_format=xml&headers=1'
```

The error I get is:

```
>>> for template_name, file_name in zip(template_name_list, file_name_list):
...
  File "<stdin>", line 2

    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
>>>
```

Comment: On stack overflow, always be sure to search for an answer before posting your question. The indented block error, for example, is a very common question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48574160/what-does-this-error-mean-expected-an-indented-block-mean/ for example.

Comment: Also, can you reformat your question using 4 spaces before each line of code to cause it to appear as your code is structured, including your current indentation?

Comment: Tried to edit the question myself. Apparently SO don't allow you to do it by saying *Your post contains only code, please add in more details*, even though this is a correct use case of the edit button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure your indentation accurately describes your intended code blocks, as they should flow. For example:

```
import urllib.request

template_name_list = ['Summercity_171128', '171219_Quarter']

file_name_list = ['Summercity_171128', '171219_Quarter']

for template_name, file_name in zip(template_name_list, file_name_list):
    url = 'http://api.whatcounts.net/bin/api_web?r=relayrides&p=******&c=gettemplatebyname&template_name='+str(template_name)+'&output_format=xml&headers=1'
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, '/Users/k/Downloads/Templates/'+str(file_name)+'.html')
```